# Rails 5: Javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some javascript inside the `app/assets/javascripts/geolocation.js` that is not loading. Checking the console for results absolutely nothing is happening. Any ideas what I'm might be doing wrong?

This is what I"m trying:

geolocation.js

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

app/views/search/search.html.erb

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "geolocation.js" %>
<% end %>
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//=require jquery
//=require jquery_ujs
//=require jquery.turbolinks
//=require turbolinks-compatibility
//=require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: `x` might not exist yet. Wrap the whole content of that file in a DOMContentLoaded handler.

Comment: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/9

Comment: Doesn't need a yield for `content_for` ?

Comment: Thanks for the info @ Sergio Tulentsev... I have been trying to wrap the javascript with a DOMContentLoaded handler but I'm having trouble doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the JavaScript file is in any of the asset folders (`assets`, `vendor` or `bundle`) for Rails 3.x, you can add the script to your `html.erb` file by adding the following:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('test.js') %>
```

Comment: I added this  `<%= javascript_include_tag('geolocation.js') %>` to the `application.html.erb`but nothing happens.  Also checked the console for any actions, but nothing happens there too. Weird